# C# SetforegroundWindow to VB.Net then SendKeys

Tags: c#, vb.net, automation, sendkeys, setforegroundwindow

I'm automating some processes. I run a VB.net application and need to input a password, tab through to the "sign in" button, send enter, tab through to the "run loads" button and hit enter. The SendKey part doesn't seem to be the problem; it's getting the right application to focus. I was hoping form.TopMost could help, but unfortunately is not the case.

```
[DllImport("User32")]
        private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(int hwnd);
        public void runDailyWS()
        {
            string homeWSPath = "D:\\...";

            var home = Process.Start(homeWSPath);

            var procName = "DataLoad Home Test - Copy";
        Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName);

        // Activate the first application we find with this name
        if (p.Count() > 0)
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle);
                SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("password");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
            }
///Did not post rest of code after this point as it's unnecessary
```

I've tried a few different ways to bring the VB.net application/process to the front and the strange thing is that it works sometimes, but sometimes isn't good enough. Does anyone have any ideas? I've looked at the first 6 or so google results, too. Thanks.

EDIT: To clarify, this code starts a VB.net application and I'm trying to automate keystrokes to enter credentials and start the application by hitting enter. In order for the keystrokes to actually register though, the VB.net application needs to be the Active window. Also changed my code to be the code that worked (it worked 1/7 tries).

Comment: I don't quite understand what your problem is. Define what it is suppose to do and what it does instead. It will help to help you. Also, small thing, but in your code snippet you are missing a `}`at the end.

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing hWnd to SetForegroundWindow() instead of arrProcesses.Length?

Comment: @Sifu That was the portion of the code I needed help with; there's more stuff afterwards that works.

Comment: @HanH1113 Then, for clarity, you should edit your question and add something like this `///Removed following working code; }`. My 2 cent.

Comment: If you know it's VB.Net, as opposed to C#, F#, or some .Net app in general, that implies you also have at least indirect access to the source code. Having made that inference, it seems like you'd do better to create direct calls into the original methods. For that matter, .Net exe files can often be used as references in other .Net apps, just as if they were dlls.

Answer (score 1):

I added `Thread.Sleep(2000);` because the code was just inputting the keystrokes before the application even had a chance to fully load. I don't know if this solution will help anyone else, but it's definitely something to consider. Thanks to those who contributed.